# SQL: CAST AS DECIMAL not accepting precision parameters

Tags: sql

I'm using CAST AS DECIMAL and specifying the precision I require.  Here is the snippet from my SQL query:

`CAST(((num/volume)*100) AS decimal(16,8)) AS impact`

No matter what I put in the parameter for decimal, the value in the impact column is always '0.00'.

This should not be the case as I have a num = 5, a volume = 81000, so this should give me '0.0061' in impact.

Please can someone explain why CAST AS DECIMAL isn't accepting my parameters to give the precision I require in the impact column?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What data types are `num` and `volume`?

Comment: Try `(num*100.0)/volume`. (_integer division_...)

Answer (score 2):

because int/int result cast as int and thats why 5 / 81000 equal 0

you can use

```
(CAST(num AS decimal(16,8)) / CAST(volume AS decimal(16,8))) * 100 AS impact
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely because your two parameters for num and volume are integers.  Cast one of those say as a decimal and you should get the answer you want.
eg

```
select CAST(((cast(num as decimal(5,2))/volume)*100) AS decimal(16,8)) AS impact
```

Answer (score 0):

Your database is clearly doing integer division.  I would just rewrite this as:

```
CAST( (num * 100.0 / volume) AS decimal(16, 8)) AS impact
```